# wordpress multiple click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to use dynamic content in my pages from WordPress; i would like to swap between YouTube video's en text. Both functions work fine separately, but i can't get them both to work

**Text function** (switchcontent.js)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a").click(function(){
        $('#tekst').text( $(this).attr('data-name'));
    });
});
```

**YouTube function** (video.js)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.vid_button').click( function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var URL = $(this).attr('href');
  //var htm = '[embed]https://youtu.be/' + URL + '[/embed]';
  var htm = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=dark&color=red&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen ></iframe>';
  $('.video_position_size').html(htm);
  return false;
 });
});
```

**Function.php**

```js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
 wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/video.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'your-script', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/switchcontent.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

Comment: remove or replace $ from function($)

Comment: replace with? removing won't work